# pass object generated in server back to ui in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I need to create an object (or variable( in my server part and pass back into ui checkboxGroupInput. My file is a little complicated. Here I just use diamonds data to illustrate what I'm trying to do, although what the app is doing is meaningless. I created a df, a subset of diamonds dataset. I'm trying to pass it back to the ui checkboxGroupInput, so that I can select what columns to show. My question is how do I pass df back to ui? thanks in advance.

Here is my app.r:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("nrow", label = h3("number of rows"), 
                        choices = list(5, 10, 20), 
                        selected = 5),
            checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in diamonds to show:",
                                   names(df), selected = names(df))
        ),
        mainPanel(
            DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1")
            )
        )
    )


server <- function(input, output) {

    # choose rows to display
    df = diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), input$nrow), ]

    output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(df[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE])
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Error message:

```
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specific error you're seeing is because you're trying to use `input$nrow` outside of any reactive context (as per the error) in this line.

```
 df = diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), input$nrow), ]
```

So this needs to be move into some sort of reactive expression

Also, you can create the UI element inside the server using `renderUI` and `uiOutput` functions. That way it's easier to control the UI from the server.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("nrow", label = h3("number of rows"), 
                  choices = list(5, 10, 20), 
                  selected = 5),
      uiOutput(outputId = "show_vars")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  # choose rows to display
  df <- reactive({
    diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), input$nrow), ]
  })

  output$show_vars <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in diamonds to show:",
                       names(df()), selected = names(df()))
  })


  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(diamonds[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thank you very much!  Why you need names(df()) ? not names(df)?

Comment: @zesla - because `df` is now a `reactive` function, so to access it you need to use `df()`